# MySQL 5 nearest points based on lat and long

Tags: mysql

I've found a lot of solutions to get the nearest points in a database based on lat/long using MySQL, but I can't find how I reference the column containing the Point data type in the query it always seems to be separate columns of lat and long.

Aside from not understanding the significance of the value `111.045` in the query this appears to be what I'm trying to accomplish, but I don't understand how to reference the coords column in the query for `distance_in_km`, or if there is a better solution since I'm using Point data types.

How do you use the `coords` column in this query for lat and lng, or is there a better (or more performant) way to do this query if you've got a couple thousand results in the table?

**Query**

`$lat` and `$lng` are pulled out of `$_POST` on server, and I'm assuming that the other `lat` and `lng` are column references.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, AsText(coords) as coords, owner, pgm, 
111.045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS({$lat}))
* COS(RADIANS(lat))
* COS(RADIANS(lng) - RADIANS({$lng}))
+ SIN(RADIANS({$lat}))
* SIN(RADIANS(lat))))
AS distance_in_km
FROM buoy_stations
ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC
LIMIT 0,5";
```

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `buoy_stations` (
  `id` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `coords` POINT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `owner` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `pgm` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `met` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  `currents` CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Google "haversine formula" to understand what this is doing.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-point-property-functions.html for how to get the coordinates from a `POINT`.

Comment: 111.045 km per degree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar for pointing out where to find this in the docs.  The final query to find the closest points ended up being:

```
SELECT id, AsText(coords) as coords, owner, pgm, 
111.045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(48.68))
* COS(RADIANS(ST_X(coords)))
* COS(RADIANS(ST_Y(coords)) - RADIANS(-125.32))
+ SIN(RADIANS(48.68))
* SIN(RADIANS(ST_X(coords)))))
AS distance_in_km
FROM buoy_stations
ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC
LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: Note you can wrap this all up in a procedure. It won't be any faster , but it will mean less typing. Alternatively, you could create a mysql function, which would be faster, but is beyond my area of expertise.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry I'll look into using a MySQL function